# Algorithm to parse irregular comma-separated values

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

Say we have a list with several descriptions of things. A description consists of comma-separated words. Lets take the following list as an example (each line is a separate description):

```
white, leather, round
black, plastic, rectangular
wood, rectangular, brown
...
```

We want parse them into the following structure: (color, material, shape)

The first two descriptions could be mapped directly into our structure. But the third one could not. Because the values are in different order: material, shape, color.

So the actual question is: how do we detect such irregular entries and parse them?

I guess we somehow have to detect what part each word describes. But i don't even know where and how to begin with that. I would also really appreciate any hints, algorithms and papers (on related algorithms).

**Edit:** Sorry forgot to mention that there is no known and fixed vocabulary. And there could be the same words in different categories.
But probably the most important thing i think i missed out is: **most of the entries are regular**. So i guess we could use that somehow to grow a dictionary.

Comment: How is the data generated? Is it something you do? Or do you take it from an external source?

Comment: Do you have a known and fixed vocabulary for color, material, and shape? Are there any overlaps (e.g., color=sand and material=sand)?

Comment: see edit for answers @TedHopp

Comment: the data is from an external source @HunterMcMillen

Comment: The simplest think to do would be to build an index of colors you want to allow and if the first value doesn't match any of those colors, throw out the whole row.

Answer (score 2):

Without constraints of some kind, this is an impossible problem. Assuming that you have some sort of dictionary to classify words (perhaps ambiguously), you can make some progress. Here's an outline of an algorithm:

1. First, parse each line as three words, without classifying them.
2. Then use the dictionary to assign to each word a set of candidate categories (color, material, and/or shape).
3. If a word has only one category, then eliminate that category from the other two words. Repeat until no further progress can be made.
4. If all words have a single category, then you're done and have found the only solution.
5. If any word has zero categories, then the three words cannot be valid in combination.
6. You now have to guess: pick a word that has more than one category and select one category as the tentative assignment for that word. Reapply the rule from step 3.
7. If any word has zero categories, backtrack to step 6 if any categories have not been tried; else exit with failure.
8. If all words have a single category, then you've found a consistent assignment. If all you need is *some* solution, then exit with this one. If you want all solutions, add this solution to a set of solutions and backtrack to step 6 for another attempt.
9. If some words still have more than one category, return to step 6 (without backtracking).

Answer (score 1):

For the first baby step, my thinking is to build dictionaries for color, material and shape, then based on this dictionaries to parse.

Otherwise, you cannot detect which word belong to which category

Answer (score 0):

Start with three word lists, materials, colors, and shapes. For each line you want to parse, try to match each entry against a word in all three lists. When you have a match put it into the related structure field. If you have 2 matches, append the third one into the unmatched list. If you can match less then 2 entries, then skip that line and try it in the second pass with a hopefully larger list. If you cannot parse the line after the, say 3rd, pass then ask the user to parse the line and append entries into related lists.

Answer (score 0):

Keep three lists for the words in each position. Given a new entry, score each word for each of the lists based on its frequency in that list (absolute frequency and/or relative to its total number of occurrences). For the word-list combination with the highest score match that word to that list. Repeat among the two words and two lists which remain. Then match the last remaining word to the last remaining list.